# Slope of any line segment of a piecewise-linear function is bounded by $M$, then so is the line segment connecting any 2 points.

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions

Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a piecewise-linear function, so that there is a partition of $I=[a,b]$:
\begin{align*}
a:=t_0<t_1<\cdots<t_n:=b
\end{align*}
such that on each $I_i:=[t_{i-1},t_i]$, $f(I_i)$ is a straight line segment $\ell_i$. Denote the absolute value of the slope of $\ell_i$ by $m_i$.

My question is as follow: Suppose $\exists M>0$ such that for all $i$, we have 
\begin{align*}
m_i\leq M
\end{align*}
Show that for any $x,y\in I$ with $x\neq y$, 
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}\right|\leq M
\end{align}
That is, the absolute value of the slope of the line segment connecting $(x,f(x))$ and $(y,f(y))$ is also no greater than $M$.

At first glance the problem seems easy. One just plays around with inequalities. However, I keep getting a less sharp result that the L.H.S. is $\leq\nu M$, where $\nu$ depends on the number of $t_i$'s between $x$ and $y$. How can I improve?

Thanks in advance for any comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $i$,
$$-M(t_i-t_{i-1})\le f(t_i)-f(t_{i-1})\le M(t_i-t_{i-1}).$$
Add these up to get
$$-M(b-a)\le f(b)-f(a)\le M(b-a).$$

But you said, **any** two points, not just the endpoints $a$
and $b$. Never mind, restricting to an subinterval gives
a piecewise linear function still with slopes between $\pm M$.